# Align bold numbers with roman ones in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, bold, number, book-class

### General overview

In TOC the page numbers of chapters (in bold) and section (in normal font) occur a ugly shift. I search a way to make them aligned.

[image: example]

### MWE

Here is a MWE to reproduce this behavior:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newpage\null
\newpage\null
\newpage\null
\newpage\null
\newpage\null
\newpage\null
\newpage\null
\newpage\null
\newpage\null
\newpage\null
\newpage\null
\newpage\null
\newpage\null
\newpage\null
\newpage\null
\newpage\null
\newpage\null
\newpage\null
\newpage\null
\newpage\null
\newpage\null
\newpage\null
\newpage\null
\newpage\null

\chapter{foo} Lipsum lorem 
\section{foo} Lipsum lorem 
\section{baz} dolor sit amet
\section{bar} dolor sit amet
\section{faa} dolor sit amet
\chapter{baz} dolor sit amet
\chapter{bar} dolor sit amet
\chapter{faa} dolor sit amet

\end{document}
```

### The question

How to force chapter page numbers to feat section page numbers (or the opposite?) in order to fix this shift?

Answer (score 0):

I found it:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont}
```